# new BigDecimal("0") NumberFormatException

Tags: java, bigdecimal, numberformatexception, icedtea

I'm having a weird problem with BigDecimal.

I have a parse method as follows:

```
protected BigDecimal parseBigDecimalFromText(String text) {
    Logger.info("parseBigDecimalFromText("+text+")");
    return new BigDecimal(text);
}
```

Now when I run my test the code properly works.

```
@Test
public void parseBigDecimalFromZero() {
    Logger.createLogger();

    // given
    String text = "0";

    // when
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = basicPage.parseBigDecimalFromText(text);

    // then
    Assert.assertEquals(new BigDecimal("0"), bigDecimal);
}
```

But when I execute my application passing exactly the same String "0" I got a "java.lang.NumberFormatException"

Following is the log:

```
2014-11-05 23:21:33.142: INFO - parseBigDecimalFromText(0) 
2014-11-05 23:21:33.142: SEVERE - null 
java.lang.NumberFormatException
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:470)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:739)
    at com.aa.travian.pages.BasicPage.parseBigDecimalFromText(BasicPage.java:121)
```

I know that when my app starts I'm setting a specific Locale:

```
Locale locale = getConfig().getLocale();
ResourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("translations", locale);
```

but I don't see how this should break my parseBigDecimalFromText method.

Following is my java version:

```
java -versionjava version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.2) (7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Any idea what is happening here?
Looking at the BigDecimal source code it looks like it falls while parsing the exponent:

```
// exponent expected
if ((c != 'e') && (c != 'E'))
    throw new NumberFormatException();
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What happens if you type manually `new BigDecimal("0")` ?

Comment: Sure there isn't a space after `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't log a string variable to verify its contents, because many many different strings are not visually distinguishable.

Instead, treat all your strings as binary data. Make a hex dump and compare that.

Here's one way of reproducing your output and problem:

```
$ cat Test.java
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import java.math.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("test");
        String text = "0\0";
        logger.info("parseBigDecimalFromText("+text+")");
        new BigDecimal(text);
    }
}

$ javac Test.java
$ java Test
Nov 06, 2014 12:55:40 AM Test main
INFO: parseBigDecimalFromText(0)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException
        at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:470)
        at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:739)
        at Test.main(Test.java:10)
$
```

Comment: That's it, there were 4 extra characters in the string that the logger couldn't print. I just printed out the lenght together with the string and it was saying 5 (no hex transformation).
Anyway I solved adding a REGEX in order to parse the string and get a Decimal number.
It looks like I have to learn how to log properly, it seems an easy task but I'm realizing it is really important! :)
Thanks very much and good spot!